# Filter Json Using Checkboxes with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, checkbox

I have been trying to solve this problem for days.
i'm trying to filter Json data using checkbox , for example when i checkbox more than one id , it shows the rest that id data 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjgHk.png)

if user selects check boxes ( model numbers ),models will be filtered based on those check boxes selection

```
    controller('compareModelsCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$state' ,'$location',
    function($scope, $http, $state,$location, filterFilter) {
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.models = data;
    $scope.whichmodel = $state.params.modelId;
 $scope.order = {}; 

  $scope.format=function(){
  $scope.modifiedOrder=[];
   angular.forEach($scope.order, function(value, key) {
    if(value){
      $scope.modifiedOrder.push(parseInt(key));
    }
});


   <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="model in models | filter:query" ng-model="order[model.id]"  ng-change="format()">{{model.model_number}}</ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item>
          current order : {{modifiedOrder}}
```

DataJson

```
{
    "id":"0",
    "model_number":"BT168562.3",
    "rotor_drawing_number":4.01591,
    "material":"17-4 PH",
    "number_of_lobes":"5/6",
    "contour_length":51.00,
    "overall_length":55.00,
    "major_dia_in":1.063,
    "minor_dia_in":0.761,
    "rotor_head_dia_in":1.000,
    "thread_form":"N/A",
    "rotor_weight_lbs":11,
    "rotor_ecc":0.0755,
    "compatibility_weatherford":"",
    "compatibility_r_&_m":"TRUE",
    "compatibility_dyna_drill":"",
    "compatibility_mono_pv":"",
    "compatibility_roper":"",
    "stator_drawing_number":4.0162,
    "stator_length_in":60.00,
    "stator_contour_in":52.00,
    "cutback_top":4.00,
    "cutback_end":4.00,
    "tube_od":1.6875,
    "tube_id_ends":1.38,
    "tube_id_middle":1.38,
    "stator_number_of_stages":2.3,
    "stator_weight_lbs":14,
    "std_vector_nbr_55":0.913,
    "std_vector_nbr_hp":0.913,
    "fit_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0.000,
    "fit_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "fit_1_0_os_vector_nbr_55":0.000,
    "fit_1_0_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "fit_1_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0.000,
    "fit_1_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "fit_2_0_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_2_0_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "2_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "2_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_1_5_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_1_5_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_1_0_us_vector_nbr_55":0.903,
    "fit_1_0_us_vector_nbr_hp":0.903,
    "fit_5_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_5_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_2_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_2_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_3_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_3_os_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "tolerance":0.010,
    "nbr_thermal_expansion_coef":0.000190,
    "nbr_hp_thermal_expansion_coef":0.000190,
    "number_of_stages":2.3,
    "rev_per_gal":9.25,
    "torque_slope_ft_lb_psi":0.29,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_55_psi":150,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_hp_psi":225,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_hpx_psi":235,
    "plot_gpm_1":20,
    "plot_gpm_2":30,
    "plot_gpm_3":40,
    "slip_at_gpm_2":"15%",
    "":0,
    "flow_range_low":20,
    "flow_range_high":40,
    "speed_range_low":185,
    "speed_range_high":370,
    "off_bottom_pressure":31,
    "max_diff_pressure_nbr":345,
    "max_diff_pressure_nbr_hpx":541,
    "stall_diff_pressure_nbr":518,
    "stall_diff_pressure_nbr_hpx":851,
    "max_torque_nbr":100,
    "max_torque_nbr_hpx":157,
    "stall_torque_nbr":185,
    "},

    "id":"1",
    "model_number":"BT168565.0",
    "rotor_drawing_number":4.01530,
    "material":"17-4 PH",
    "number_of_lobes":"5/6",
    "contour_length":87.00,
    "overall_length":93.00,
    "major_dia_in":0.990,
    "minor_dia_in":0.714,
    "rotor_head_dia_in":1.100,
    "thread_form":"N/A",
    "rotor_weight_lbs":16,
    "rotor_ecc":0.0690,
    "compatibility_weatherford":"",
    "compatibility_r_&_m":"TRUE",
    "compatibility_dyna_drill":"",
    "compatibility_mono_pv":"",
    "compatibility_roper":"TRUE",
    "stator_drawing_number":4.01637,
    "stator_length_in":99.00,
    "stator_contour_in":91.00,
    "cutback_top":4.00,
    "cutback_end":4.00,
    "tube_od":1.6875,
    "tube_id_ends":1.38,
    "tube_id_middle":1.38,
    "stator_number_of_stages":5.0,
    "stator_weight_lbs":27,
    "std_vector_nbr_55":0.853,
    "std_vector_nbr_hp":0.853,
    "fit_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0.000,
    "fit_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "fit_1_0_os_vector_nbr_55":0.863,
    "fit_1_0_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.863,
    "fit_1_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0.000,
    "fit_1_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "fit_2_0_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_2_0_os_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "2_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "2_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_1_5_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_1_5_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_1_0_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_1_0_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_5_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_5_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_2_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_2_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_3_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_3_os_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "tolerance":0.010,
    "nbr_thermal_expansion_coef":0.000190,
    "nbr_hp_thermal_expansion_coef":0.000190,
    "number_of_stages":5.0,
    "rev_per_gal":15.72,
    "torque_slope_ft_lb_psi":0.19,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_55_psi":150,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_hp_psi":225,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_hpx_psi":235,
    "plot_gpm_1":25,
    "plot_gpm_2":40,
    "plot_gpm_3":55,
    "slip_at_gpm_2":"15%",
    "":0,
    "flow_range_low":25,
    "flow_range_high":55,
    "speed_range_low":393,
    "speed_range_high":865,
    "off_bottom_pressure":67,
    "max_diff_pressure_nbr":750,
    "max_diff_pressure_nbr_hpx":1175,
    "stall_diff_pressure_nbr":1125,
    "stall_diff_pressure_nbr_hpx":1851,
    "max_torque_nbr":143,
    "max_torque_nbr_hpx":223,
    "stall_torque_nbr":393,
    "stall_torque_nbr_hpx":865
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated , Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what your end data should look like? In other words, the question is not clear. What is the goal? Do you want the IDs that are not selected?

Comment: no , when i checkbox two or more ids , it shows the id along with it other information on the datajson  like ( material , number_of_lobes ) and so on , like a compare page between the ids and it's values

Comment: The question is still not clear. You have been saying it shows the id along with other information? Where is it showing? OR Do you want another  filtered `JSON` out of that `JSON data` based on the selected ids?

Comment: yes exactly  , when i choose two ids for example , it suppose to shows other 2 values along with  that chosen ids .

Comment: after select the id , i wanna be able to show other proprieties  along with that id  , for example like in data-json , when i select id 0 , i need to show (rotor_drawing_number":4.01591,,"material":"17-4 PH") from id 0 , and so on if i choose 2 or more ids .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off make sure the JSON data or Models is as

```
[{
    "id":"0",
    "model_number":"BT168562.3",
    "rotor_drawing_number":4.01591,
    "material":"17-4 PH",
    "number_of_lobes":"5/6",
    "contour_length":51.00,
    "overall_length":55.00,
    "major_dia_in":1.063,
    "minor_dia_in":0.761,
    "rotor_head_dia_in":1.000,
    "thread_form":"N/A",
    "rotor_weight_lbs":11,
    "rotor_ecc":0.0755,
    "compatibility_weatherford":"",
    "compatibility_r_&_m":"TRUE",
    "compatibility_dyna_drill":"",
    "compatibility_mono_pv":"",
    "compatibility_roper":"",
    "stator_drawing_number":4.0162,
    "stator_length_in":60.00,
    "stator_contour_in":52.00,
    "cutback_top":4.00,
    "cutback_end":4.00,
    "tube_od":1.6875,
    "tube_id_ends":1.38,
    "tube_id_middle":1.38,
    "stator_number_of_stages":2.3,
    "stator_weight_lbs":14,
    "std_vector_nbr_55":0.913,
    "std_vector_nbr_hp":0.913,
    "fit_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0.000,
    "fit_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "fit_1_0_os_vector_nbr_55":0.000,
    "fit_1_0_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "fit_1_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0.000,
    "fit_1_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "fit_2_0_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_2_0_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "2_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "2_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_1_5_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_1_5_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_1_0_us_vector_nbr_55":0.903,
    "fit_1_0_us_vector_nbr_hp":0.903,
    "fit_5_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_5_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_2_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_2_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_3_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_3_os_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "tolerance":0.010,
    "nbr_thermal_expansion_coef":0.000190,
    "nbr_hp_thermal_expansion_coef":0.000190,
    "number_of_stages":2.3,
    "rev_per_gal":9.25,
    "torque_slope_ft_lb_psi":0.29,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_55_psi":150,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_hp_psi":225,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_hpx_psi":235,
    "plot_gpm_1":20,
    "plot_gpm_2":30,
    "plot_gpm_3":40,
    "slip_at_gpm_2":"15%",
    "":0,
    "flow_range_low":20,
    "flow_range_high":40,
    "speed_range_low":185,
    "speed_range_high":370,
    "off_bottom_pressure":31,
    "max_diff_pressure_nbr":345,
    "max_diff_pressure_nbr_hpx":541,
    "stall_diff_pressure_nbr":518,
    "stall_diff_pressure_nbr_hpx":851,
    "max_torque_nbr":100,
    "max_torque_nbr_hpx":157,
    "stall_torque_nbr":185,
    },

    {"id":"1",
    "model_number":"BT168565.0",
    "rotor_drawing_number":4.01530,
    "material":"17-4 PH",
    "number_of_lobes":"5/6",
    "contour_length":87.00,
    "overall_length":93.00,
    "major_dia_in":0.990,
    "minor_dia_in":0.714,
    "rotor_head_dia_in":1.100,
    "thread_form":"N/A",
    "rotor_weight_lbs":16,
    "rotor_ecc":0.0690,
    "compatibility_weatherford":"",
    "compatibility_r_&_m":"TRUE",
    "compatibility_dyna_drill":"",
    "compatibility_mono_pv":"",
    "compatibility_roper":"TRUE",
    "stator_drawing_number":4.01637,
    "stator_length_in":99.00,
    "stator_contour_in":91.00,
    "cutback_top":4.00,
    "cutback_end":4.00,
    "tube_od":1.6875,
    "tube_id_ends":1.38,
    "tube_id_middle":1.38,
    "stator_number_of_stages":5.0,
    "stator_weight_lbs":27,
    "std_vector_nbr_55":0.853,
    "std_vector_nbr_hp":0.853,
    "fit_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0.000,
    "fit_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "fit_1_0_os_vector_nbr_55":0.863,
    "fit_1_0_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.863,
    "fit_1_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0.000,
    "fit_1_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0.000,
    "fit_2_0_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_2_0_os_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "2_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "2_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_1_5_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_1_5_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_1_0_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_1_0_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_5_us_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_5_us_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_2_5_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_2_5_os_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "fit_3_os_vector_nbr_55":0,
    "fit_3_os_vector_nbr_hp":0,
    "tolerance":0.010,
    "nbr_thermal_expansion_coef":0.000190,
    "nbr_hp_thermal_expansion_coef":0.000190,
    "number_of_stages":5.0,
    "rev_per_gal":15.72,
    "torque_slope_ft_lb_psi":0.19,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_55_psi":150,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_hp_psi":225,
    "pressure_per_stage_nbr_hpx_psi":235,
    "plot_gpm_1":25,
    "plot_gpm_2":40,
    "plot_gpm_3":55,
    "slip_at_gpm_2":"15%",
    "":0,
    "flow_range_low":25,
    "flow_range_high":55,
    "speed_range_low":393,
    "speed_range_high":865,
    "off_bottom_pressure":67,
    "max_diff_pressure_nbr":750,
    "max_diff_pressure_nbr_hpx":1175,
    "stall_diff_pressure_nbr":1125,
    "stall_diff_pressure_nbr_hpx":1851,
    "max_torque_nbr":143,
    "max_torque_nbr_hpx":223,
    "stall_torque_nbr":393,
    "stall_torque_nbr_hpx":865
  }]
```

There was formating issue in your question.

Second, you need to use filter function. I have created a filtered object named as `selectedObjects` and modified the value in the `format` function and displayed in `HTML` as follows.

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="model in models | filter:query" ng-model="order[model.id]"  ng-change="format()">{{model.model_number}}</ion-checkbox>
     <pre>
    current order : {{modifiedOrder}} <br>
    selected objects:{{selectedObjects}} </pre>
```

And JS

> This implementation assumes that id is unique in JSON.

```
$scope.order = {};
        $scope.format = function() {
              $scope.modifiedOrder = [];
              $scope.selectedObjects = [];
              angular.forEach($scope.order, function(value, key) {
                    if (value) {
                          var filtered = $scope.models.filter(function(unit) {
                                return unit.id === key
                          });
                          $scope.selectedObjects.push({
                                   "overall_length":filtered[0].overall_length,
                                "contour_length": filtered[0].contour_length
                          });

                          $scope.modifiedOrder.push(parseInt(key));
                    }
              });
        }
```

Find sample implementation here.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLNJzB?editors=1010
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help , but it shows me the whole datajson  like this http://i.imgur.com/mON5fCC.png , how can i only pick one or two

Comment: What do you mean by pick one or two? If you just need to pick one or two items from JSON you now need to modify that JSON after being filtered.

Comment: I mean it return the whole json data , i just wanted to return item or two . how can i modify it to return  for example contour_length":51.00, and 
    "overall_length":55.00, instead of the all info

Comment: I'm sorry i couldn't explain well , but something similar  to this http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2015/12/filter-json-data-with-check-boxes-using.html#.V9DJG7l97VP

Comment: Didn't it solve your issue? If yes please accept answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot , you saved me :)

Comment: is there any way I can  display   those two values separately in html page?

Comment: the code works great , lastly I'm trying to display the two values inside selectedObjects separately  in html page ? 
Thanks a lot for your help and time

Comment: Post a question clarifying things you want an answer for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397661/display-items-from-checkbox-array-angularjs