# Render local PDF files in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have been trying to open PDF files in a Ionic app.
I have tried many Cordova FileOpener2  plugin and in app browser, none of them worked.

Those are the functions I tried , when I test it in the browser it gives me error " cordova is not defiened , and when I test it on the emulator or on the phone , the functions doesn't work:

```
$scope.openPDFI = function(){

    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/pdfs/BT168562.3.pdf', // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/starwars.pdf
    'application/pdf', 
    { 
        error : function(e) { 
            console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
        },
        success : function () {
            console.log('file opened successfully');                
        }
    }
)
};
**/
 /**$scope.openPDFI = function() {

   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory +  'www/pdfs/BT168562.3.pdf', function(fileEntry) {

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dirEntry) {

        fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry, uri.split('/').pop(), function(newFileEntry) {

            window.open(newFileEntry.nativeURL, '_system');
        });
    });
});
 };
 **/



  //  $scope.openPDF = function() {
  //window.open('www/pdfs/BT168562.3.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes');
//};


       /**
$scope.openPDFf = function(filename) {

newfilename = 'file.pdf'
uri = '/www/pdfs/' + filename;
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + uri, function(fileEntry) {

  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dirEntry) {

    fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry, newfilename, function(newFileEntry) {

      window.open(newFileEntry.nativeURL, '_system', 'location=yes');
    });
  });
});
};
**/
 /**$scope.openPDF = function(){
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory +  'www/pdfs/BT168562.3.pdf', function(fileEntry) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dirEntry) {
        fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry, 'file.pdf', function(newFileEntry) {
            cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(newFileEntry.nativeURL,'application/pdf',
            { 
                error : function(e) { 
                    console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                },
                success : function () {
                    console.log('file opened successfully');                
                }
            }
            );
        });
    });
});
};
**/
 /**$scope.downloadFile= function() {
        $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
            '/sdcard/pdfs/BT168562.3.pdf',
            'application/pdf'
        ).then(function() {
            console.log('Success');
        }, function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    };    **/       


/**
$scope.onFileOpen =function() {
        cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
            cordova.file.applicationDirectory + '/www/pdfs/BT168562.3.pdf',
            'application/pdf',
            {
                error: function() {

                },
                success: function() {

                }
            }
        );
    }


$scope.loadPDF =function () {
    console.log('loadPDF1');
    document.location.href='pdfs/BT168562.3.pdf';
}

$scope.openPDF =  function () {
    console.log('openPdf');
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('pdfs/BT168562.3.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no');
}

/** $scope.loadPDF =function () {
    console.log('loadPDF3');
    console.log(cordova.file.applicationDirectory);
    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        cordova.file.applicationDirectory+'www/pdfs/BT168562.3.pdf',
        'application/pdf', 
        { 
            error : function(e) { 
                console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
            },
            success : function () {
                console.log('file opened successfully');                
            }
        }
    );
} 

<button ng-click="onFileOpen()">Open pdf</button> </br>
                <button ng-click="loadPDF()">load pdf</button>
```

Any idea on how can I do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cordova is not loaded in the ionic when you try to debug in a web browser itself. Read this to debug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332853/is-there-a-real-solution-to-debug-cordova-apps

Comment: yes i know , but also it's not working on the device or emulator . i need a function that  work  , i tried those above and they didn't work

Comment: @Amr Ayoub try out this working sample in device - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: @Gandhi it looks good , but this phonegap code , how can  i implement this on ionic application

Comment: @Amr Ayoub you jus have to use ionic equivalent plugins of the same. The code remains the same. Only change may be to use plugin code in platform ready function instead of device ready

Comment: @Gandhi Thank you , i will try and let you know how did it go :)

Comment: @Gandhi I spent hours trying it but didn't work , i test it on the phone and nothing show up , i guess it an issue with the file path , any help please

Comment: @AmrAyoub Unfortunately i dont have ionic setup for me to test. But you could send me the apk for testing